# AdaBoost Error in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, predict, adaboost

When I am trying to do boosting function in R using "adabag" library:

`adaboost = boosting(count~., data=train, boos=TRUE, mfinal=100, coeflearn='Breiman')`

I am getting this error:

`Error in predict.rpart(fit, newdata = data[, -1], type = "class"): 
  Invalid prediction for "rpart" object`

Comment: We can only guess, since you don't provide a reproducible example.  But what is `fit` in your code? Did you mean `adaboost` instead of `fit`?

Comment: @Andrie I have no idea what _fit_ is. I don't have such variable. Maybe it is, somewhere in _boosting_.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?